# perl API for Apache Spark?

Tags: perl, apache-spark

I'm a longtime perl developer and I've been told to "go learn Apache Spark".
So my plan is, 1) figure out what Apache spark is, 2) figure out how to
talk to it with perl.  We are early in the process here...

I see a lot of web pages like
https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/05/apache-spark-python-scala.html
that say "Though Spark has API’s for Scala, Python, Java
and R but the popularly used languages are the former two."

Nowhere have I found anything about a perl API for Spark -- searching CPAN turned up
a couple things with 'Spark' in the name, but nothing actually relevant.
This is perplexing ... how can one of the most popular APIs for Spark be
Python-oriented, yet for perl there's nothing out there?

I'm having trouble accepting that "you can only talk to Spark via Python,
not perl", but that's where I'm at so far.  So my question is, how is the perl
community interfacing with Apache Spark, and how does this facility compare to
the Python facility, in terms of feature-completeness?

Answer (score 2):

It appears there is indeed no Perl API on CPAN or otherwise. What I've observed others doing is calling Perl scripts from Scala : https://wiki.ufal.ms.mff.cuni.cz/spark:recipes:using-perl-via-pipes

The documentation at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html says in regards to pipes:

> Pipe each partition of the RDD through a shell command, e.g. a Perl or bash script. RDD elements are written to the process's stdin and lines output to its stdout are returned as an RDD of strings.

It should be noted that python is support is via a [java gateway](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py).

The equivalent could be done in Perl using a distro such as [Java](https://metacpan.org/pod/Java).